# How can I add functionality to my addition, subtraction etc buttons on react js calculator

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my first react project with hooks. I know the code is messy, but I just want to get the gist first, then organize the code later once it's complete. But I have a calculator app that I'm building and I need help with the state. I have two states, and I need help displaying the answer. The number buttons work, but I cant figure out the code for the functional buttons like addition, subtraction etc.

tried an example with

```
handleMultiplication(e){
setNumber(math(number * 2)
```

it works, but I want to be able in input another number and hit the equal sign, then display the answer.

```
function Calculator() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState('')
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value={number} readOnly />
        <input value={answer} readOnly />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber([])} label="AC" value="clear">
          AC
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => handleClick()}
          label="+-"
          value="positivenegative"
        >
          +-
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => handlePercentage()} value="percentage">
          %
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => handleDivision()} value="division">
          /
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 7)} value="7">
          7
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 8)} value="8">
          8
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 9)}value="9">
          9
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => handleMultiplication()} value="multiplication">
          *
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 6)} value="6">
          6
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 5)} value="5">
          5
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 4)} value="4">
          4
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => handleSubtraction()} value="subtraction">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 3)} value="3">
          3
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 2)} value="2">
          2
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 1)} value="1">
          1
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => handleAddition()} value="addition">
          +
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 0)} label="0" value="0">
          0
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick()} label="." value="decimal">
          .
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick()} label="=" value="equal">
          =
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you came up with a different solution, please share it  otherwise, if it was helpful, accept my answer. Both could be useful to other users 

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assembled a rough version of the calculator with only the addition operation, it's up to you to study it and implement the other operations, is it ok?

My working addition-only calculator is [available on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0kl6z06pv), I started from your code and removed some buttons.

NOTE: this is just one (and not 100% the best way) to implement a calculator but it's out of my scope to give you a full tutorial about it.

That's my code

```
import React from "react";

function Calculator() {
  // the list will be an array of numbers and operators, ex. [10, "+", 5]
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);
  // when append is set to true, a new element is pushed to the list,
  // when it's set to false it means that it must change the last number
  const [append, setAppend] = React.useState(true);
  // the result at the last "=" button click
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState();
  // for the "AC" click
  const reset = () => {
    setList([]);
    setAppend(true);
  };

  // every number and operator click must invoke this callback
  const appendItem = item => {
    // the original list isn't mutated
    let newList = [...list];
    // if the user clicked a number button...
    if (typeof item === "number") {
      let number = item;
      if (append) {
        // the number is appended to the list
        newList.push(item);
        setAppend(false);
      } else {
        // the last aded number must be updated
        number = newList[newList.length - 1];
        number = number * 10 + item;
        newList[newList.length - 1] = number;
      }
      setList(newList);
    } else {
      // the operator must be appended...
      setList([...list, item]);
      // ... and the next number too
      setAppend(true);
    }
  };
  const calculateResult = () => {
    const result = list.reduce((acc, item, i, array) => {
      if (typeof item === "number") {
        if (i === 0) {
          return item;
        } else {
          const operator = array[i - 1];
          switch (operator) {
            case "+":
              return acc + item;
            default:
              return acc;
          }
        }
      }
      return acc;
    }, 0);
    setResult(result);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value={list.join("")} readOnly />
        <input value={result} readOnly />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={reset} label="AC" value="clear">
          AC
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem(7)} value="7">
          7
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem(8)} value="8">
          8
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem(9)} value="9">
          9
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem(6)} value="6">
          6
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem(5)} value="5">
          5
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem(4)} value="4">
          4
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem(3)} value="3">
          3
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem(2)} value="2">
          2
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem(1)} value="1">
          1
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem("+")} value="addition">
          +
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => appendItem(0)} label="0" value="0">
          0
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => calculateResult()} label="=" value="equal">
          =
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Calculator;
```

I commented on it and, as you can see, the biggest improvement is about state management, I use three states:

- one for the number/operations list
- one to know when or not I should append the item to the list (a `"+"` or a number following a `"+"`) or when I should update the last number added (when you press `1` twice, the previous `1` should become `11`)
- one for the result

Most of the complexity comes from managing the list of number/operations, anyway: let me know if the comments aren't sufficient to understand how it works